# Undervotage detected while using UPS hat (b) on wheel robot

Tags: gpio, power-supply, ups, robotics

I am doing a mecanum wheel robot project included 2 motor drivers l298n. I use raspberry pi 4 GPIO to control the motor drivers and my power supply for rpi is an UPS hat (b). I keep receiving undervoltage warning and the rpi keep rebooting itself while the robot was functioning. Someone please help me.

[image: This is my setup.]

The motors are dc gear yellow motors with Operating voltage : 3 – 12V, Torque : 800 gf-cm min @ 3V, Gear ratio : 1:48, No-load current : 150mA @ 3V / 200mA @ 6V

Comment: Sounds like your motors are drawing more power than your supply can provide starving the Pi of power. How is it powered?

Comment: 4 motors and 2 motor drivers are powered with 2 18650 battery (3.7v - 2800mAh), the pi  only output control signal through GPIO

Comment: What is the spec of the motors? How many amps can they draw? Must be a 3.7v to 5v converter - what is its spec?

Comment: The motors are yellow gear motor  Operating voltage : 3 – 12V, 
Torque : 800 gf-cm min @ 3V, 
Gear ratio : 1:48, 
No-load current : 150mA @ 3V / 200mA @ 6V,

Comment: So 4 motors with no load is 0.8Amps, I bet that is way more with load. Definitely overloading your UPS hat.

Comment: Should I increase number of batteries for the motors?

Comment: DO NOT put details in Comments - edit your Question. If you are getting a low voltage warning the voltage is too low but this is NOT a Pi problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're over-loading your UPS-HAT. You haven't actually asked a question, but that is your problem. If you want help, you're going to have to do a better job of illustrating your setup/configuration. FOR EXAMPLE: We have no idea what your UPS-HAT specs are.